# how to iterate over each row whose third cell has a rowspan attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; row = tableAppointment.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    //iterate through columns
    //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop.
  }
}
```

How to iterate over each row whose third cell has a `rowspan` attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give you all of the `<tr>` that have such an element in them:

```
$('td:nth-child(3)[rowspan]').parent()
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/52aR2/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr").filter( function() {
    return this.cells[2].hasAttribute("rowspan");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52aR2/2/

Or

```
for (var i = 0; row = tableAppointment.rows[i]; i++) {
    if( row.cells[2].hasAttribute("rowspan") {
        //This is a row that matches
    }
}
```

Comment: see my quetion.i have added image if rowspan is found i have to find start time and end time

Comment: @Nikhil so you want me to find the start time and end time now? Bait and switch much?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$('tr').filter( function() {
    return $('td:eq(2)',this).attr( 'rowspan' ) !== undefined;
} ).css( 'border', '1px solid red')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gMRk/

Comment: Nicola see my quetion.i have added image if rowspan is found i have to find start time and end time

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
if (cell[2].hasAttribute('rowspan')) {
   // do something here
}
```

Uses [`element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(tableAppointment.rows).
    filter(function(row) { return row.cells[2].rowSpan > 1; }).
    forEach(function(row) {
        // do something with row
    });
```

Whoaaa, look mum, no jQuery!

Comment: You can do this with `1*n` instead of `3*n` though. `[].forEach.call( rows, fn )`

Comment: The guys over W3C/TC39 deserve stale beer for these "Array like" objects.

Comment: @skrat I disagree - do we _really_ want every collection to inherit the `Array` prototype?  In any event, at least the Array methods do all (mostly?) work for Array-like objects when invoked via `.call()`.

Comment: a live nodelist is nothing like array, it wouldn't make any sense because many of the methods would never work on it.

Comment: I didn't say they should all have Array.prototype up there, I said the methods on Array.prototype are equally useful for "most" collections we deal with. Look at python, `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc. are built-in functions applicable to any iterable object, and it makes (almost) everyone happy. But no, let's stick with imperative for(;;), like it's ... who knows?

Comment: @skrat actually firefox has solved this by putting them as properties in the Array constructor. `Array.forEach( rows, fn )` for example. But I don't agree with putting them to the prototype of all kinds of collections.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the right answer.

```
$('td:nth-child(3)[rowspan]').parent()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('td:nth-child(3)[rowspan]').parent()
```

Comment: @Nikhil  huh?!  You accepted this late answer that's a direct copy of my original answer and that _didn't_ include a demo to prove it works?!